# Adding external js script dynamically to iFrame and execute function from it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I'm creating an iFrame dynamically and I've injected an external js library to it.
Everything is working fine. I have my iFrame builded containing the script tag with the library in the head tag of the library. Now I would like to execute a function that is written in that library. Here is the code that I use to add the script dynamically:

```
var head = parentFrameContentWindow.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = parentFrameContentWindow.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://localhost:8080/project/js/project-interactions.js";
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onload = function() {

    }
    head.appendChild(script)
```

I've added the onload attribut to the script tag but when I try to fire up a simple function that triggers an alert method contained but the external library, I get and undefined function error. Someone knows how to achieve that ?

Comment: since script is ok,just append another to iframe, this may have security issue, so may not cross borowser

Comment: The iframe is not on other domain so there shoudn't be cross scripting issues

Comment: then why not use post message https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage